# What is the best way to access the JWT from node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html

I have implemented JWT authentication using Node.js. When the user signs in, Node.js signs/creates a JWT and sends it back. Thereafter, it is stored in the localStorage. Now, this is probably where I am going wrong, but... to move forward, I make use of the express router, and within the router code (which is obviously at the node level) I want to be able to access the token (which is in `localStorage`) so that I can make a call to the API for further data. However, I just realised that localStorage is at the client-end and that node/express/router doesn't recognise `localStorage`. So I am stuck. Obviously, I am doing something fundamentally wrong... I should not need to access `localStorage` from the express router file. Perhaps, I should really be making the API calls not from the express router file, but from client side.

Any hints/directions?

Comment: *"Perhaps, I should really be making the API calls not from the express router file, but from client side."* seems like that'd be better all round, assuming you don't need to send any private keys or "hidden" information from the server to the client to accomplish it.

Comment: Cool, and thank you for the advice. It's nice to see that I was thinking along the right lines. Many thanks.

Answer (score -2):

localstorage is bad way to save token. you should save token in cookies and use then where you want.

EXAMPLE:

```
new Cookies(req,res).set('access_token',token,{
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true      // for your production environment
});
```

and then read:

```
var token = new Cookies(req,res).get('access_token');
```

Comment: What makes local storage a worse choice than cookies? How it's stored on the client isn't relevant to the server side. The only real issues are how the request is formed and if there are both HTTP and HTTPS pages. (I use a cookie, I just don't see any major downside to getting it from local storage and setting the request header.)

Comment: Cookies are primarily for reading server-side, local storage can only be read client-side

Comment: localStorage is an implementation of the Storage Interface. It stores data with no expiration date, and gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser Cache / Locally Stored Data - unlike cookie expiry.

Comment: Yes, I know that-but it's easy enough to set the proper header.

Comment: I am not against using cookies, but the JWT's are supposed to be sessionless in nature, and so user info is not stored at the server-side. Using cookies instead of localStorage just so that I can access the tokens at the server-side like that seems so wrong. The only way that I should be able to access the tokens at the router code (i.e. server-side code) is if I retrieve them from the request. So I am still feeling like I need to move my API calling from express to the client-side.

Answer (score -2):

You need to send the JWT that is stored on the client side every time you make an API request to the server side.

https://jwt.io/introduction/
Scroll down to the section **How do JSON Web Tokens work?** The JWT should be sent in the header of the API calls in the form:
`Authorization: Bearer <token>`

How you do this depends on how exactly you'll send the HTTP requests to the API, but it should be pretty simple in any respects. You can find out about how to add Headers to an angular $http request at this link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Then it's up for each of your authenticated express routes to check the headers, pull the JWT out, ensure that it's valid, and then proceed with the request (or halt it if the JWT is invalid).

Comment: Thank you. However, to send the JWT every time to an API, I need to extract it from localStorage first. That is my main problem, I am not able to do so because localStorage is not available at the node/express level.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think you need to extract it from localStorage on the client side, and then send it to node/express via an HTTP request. Isn't your server side running a node/express server, and the client side just the browser? Or am I incorrect? You absolutely should be making API calls from the client to the server.